# How to get ground state wave function in path integral method?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, wavefunction, path-integral, ground-state

For a fermion field with the nearest interaction on a square lattice. How once could determine ground state field or ground state wave function in path integrals? In general how one can determine wave functions of a quantum system using path integrals. Please explain in detail and suggest some materials to read upon and to have a clear picture about this.

Comment: People only know how to get the ground state wave function of a free fermion system in the path integral. Just complete the Grassmannian integral, and the result is the determinant of the occupied orbitals.

Comment: I am getting partition funtion and green's function . Can you please make it clear as I don't how to proceed further to get ground state wave function using  green's function.